# Query phpMyAdmin to only show rows with certain values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do a query in phpMyAdmin but I'm not quite sure how to do it..

The following query pulls in too much data:

```
SELECT * FROM `options` ORDER BY `option_name` ASC
```

I want to refine it so the column called `option_name` if it's value is `canceled` then it will only show those values...

Similarly I want to do a query where the `option_name` contains `where_d`

I tried the following in various forms:

```
WHERE option_name=`canceled`
```

But still nothing... any ideas?

EDIT:

```
SELECT * FROM `options` WHERE option_name LIKE 'where_d%'
```

Doesn't work :(

Comment: if you're looking if it CONTAINS that value use `LIKE `%canceled%``

Comment: @MattBusche I'm unable to figure out what you meant :S closest I got was: 

    SELECT * FROM `options` WHERE option_name LIKE 'where_d'

Comment: Backticks (`) are NOT inverted commas (')

Comment: @Strawberry see my last edit, I added one but it doesn't work for some reason...

Comment: Still struggling? Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 1):

You want single quotes, not backticks, for a value/string.

```
SELECT * FROM `options` WHERE option_name='canceled';
```